# No hello World output for Neo4j

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j

I am just starting out with Neo4j and this is my first stackoverflow question!

I tried to run the Hello-World example in Eclipse with the user library of Neo4j.
( https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.2/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java)

I only changed the `DB_PATH='data/graph.db'` ( because in my neo4j-server.properties :`org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db`)

The output I got in the console is:

> Hello, brave Neo4j World! Shutting down database ...

I shut down the neo4j server using `/etc/init.d/neo4j-service stop`, then ran eclipse and got the output as provided above.I started the neo4j server again and checked localhost:7474 through the browser. There were no rows added to the database.

Is there an error in my DB_PATH? I even tried neoeclipse but did not get any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example creates and then deletes the data so that is one reason why your graph is empty.

Another observation is your `DB_PATH`. If you've set `DB_PATH='data/graph.db'`, then that path is relative to your project path. If your code is located in `/projects/example` then this embedded database should be created in `/projects/example/data/graph.db`

If that's the case, then the Neo4j server which is configured to look for the database as `org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db` will look for `data/graph.db` relative to your *neo4j* installation.

So you can either fix the path in your code (full path to the db), or change the path in `neo4j-server.properties`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had commented removeData(). As per your suggestion I changed the DB_PATH to 'var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db'- still not working.

Comment: After your code executes, is there a database in var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db?

Comment: I tired '/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db' but got this  Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.id

Comment: Please change to a directory in which you have permissions to write. And then change your neo4j-server.properties to point to that directory.

Comment: The error is definitely in the DB_PATH as data/graph.db are getting created in the workspace. How do I give it sudo permission within eclipse? Changing the conf properties does not seem like a viable option every time.

Comment: data/graph.db is created within the workspace- so what is the full path to that? neo4j-server.properties is referring to data/graph.db in the neo4j install directory, not your workspace.You can modify the permissions on neo4j-install/data/graph.db so that the eclipse process can access it.